# The connection button on the sql developer is gone. What is wrong?

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper

[image]

I downloaded the Oracle database and sql developer for spring study. However, the connection button has disappeared and cannot proceed with the study.

Comment: I can't tell what those buttons say, but save your connection...then on the connection tree, right click on the connection and connect.

Comment: Also you need to provide a name for the connection, and, do you have a database?

Comment: I solved it with your help. thank you